# Tabela vazia ("Empty DataFrame") e ambiguidade de comparação no Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, estou tentando a uns dias montar um programa, o grosso nele está funcionando porém existem duas exigências que não se realizam de jeito nenhum. que são elas:

- Quantidade e o total cobrado de exames envolvendo EcoDoppler e Doppler que foram efetuados;
- Quantidade de exames com valores unitários("vl_unit") 30% acima ou abaixo do valor de referência("vl_ref").

No primeiro eu já tentei usar todo tipo de comando para realizar a busca das palavras "Doppler" e "Ecodoppler", porém ele só me retorna Empty DataFrame; se caso eu colocar  na busca da coluna servico >= Doppler ele me retorna uma lista de palavras que até contem o doppler mas também retornar palavras que não contem ao mesmo tempo, mas se eu colocar == ele da uma tabela vazia e se eu colocar <= funciona tambpem porem no mesmo esquema do >=.

E no segundo eu já tentei usar todo tipo de separação para a condição if comparar mas ele sempre fala que o termo está ambíguo, não sei mais o que fazer para conferir se tem algum numero na coluna "vl_unit" que seja 30% maior, ou menor, na "vl_ref".

Segue o Código:

```
import pandas as pd

contas= pd.read_csv('contas.csv', sep = ';')

#Quantidade e o total cobrado de exames envolvendo EcoDoppler e Doppler foram efetuados
doppler = contas.query("servico == 'Doppler'")
dopplerMaior = contas.query("servico >= 'Doppler'")
print("\n\nTabela vazia:\n",doppler)
print("\n\nTabela mostrando o dopplerMaior (que não é o que quero): \n",dopplerMaior['servico'])
#Quantidadede exames com valores unitários 30% acima ou abaixo do valor de referência
MaiorQueTrinta = []
if ((contas['vl_unit']) == (contas['vl_ref']*(1.3))):
    MaiorQueTrinta.append(contas['vl_unit'])
print(MaiorQueTrinta)
```

Gostaria apenas de saber o que está acontecendo e o que está dando errado. Para malhor ajuda vou colocar um treixo do arquivo CSV para teste:

```
matric;sexo; idade ;atend;tuss;servico;plano;vl_unit;vl_ref;qtde
14993;F; 60 ;06/12/2017;20201010;ACOMPANHAMENTO CLINICO DE TRANSPLANTE RENAL NO PERIODO DE INTERNACAO DO RECEPTOR;1077 ;210.00;202.01;1
10258;F; 27 ;14/03/2016;31602037;ANESTESIA GERAL OU CONDUTIVA PARA REALIZACAO DE BLOQUEIO NEUROLITICO;1145 ;492.99;316.02;1
12343;M; 86 ;14/02/2016;16020065;ANESTESIA P/ANGIOGRAFIA CAROTIDA BILAT;1132 ;338.02;160.20;2
10535;M; 50 ;14/07/2016;16020065;ANESTESIA P/ANGIOGRAFIA CAROTIDA BILAT;1091 ;325.21;160.20;11
11500;F; 38 ;31/08/2016;16020065;ANESTESIA P/ANGIOGRAFIA CAROTIDA BILAT;1112 ;257.92;160.20;4
10352;F; 14 ;05/09/2017;10101020;CONSULTA EM DOMICILIO;1127 ;107.07;101.01;1
11096;F; 62 ;08/09/2017;10101020;CONSULTA EM DOMICILIO;1190 ;208.08;101.01;1
10616;F; 45 ;01/10/2016;40901360;DOPPLER COLORIDO DE VASOS CERVICAIS ARTERIAIS BILATERAL (CAROTIDAS E VERTEBRAIS);1069 ;625.79;409.01;1
11861;M; 57 ;02/11/2016;40901360;DOPPLER COLORIDO DE VASOS CERVICAIS ARTERIAIS BILATERAL (CAROTIDAS E VERTEBRAIS);1075 ;392.65;409.01;1
13610;F; 58 ;07/03/2016;40901076;ECODOPPLERCARDIOGRAMA COM ESTRESSE FARMACOLOGICO;1085 ;797.57;409.01;2
10191;M; 29 ;24/10/2016;40901076;ECODOPPLERCARDIOGRAMA COM ESTRESSE FARMACOLOGICO;1065 ;813.93;409.01;1
14771;M; 56 ;27/09/2017;31602614;PORTE ANESTESICO 2;1011 ;445.60;316.03;4
10023;M; 59 ;28/09/2017;31602614;PORTE ANESTESICO 2;1003 ;347.63;316.03;1
```

Por favor, preciso muito apenas dessas duas condições.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Você pode buscar entradas no DataFrame da seguinte forma:

```
df_with_filter = df[ df['coluna'] == 'condicao' ]
```

Na questão de verificar dois valores da mesma linha que satisfaçam uma condição, você precisa iterar sobre cada valor dentro de um dataframe.

Para obter os valores de um DataFrame, basta usar `df.values`.

O código abaixo usa esses métodos que comentei anteriormente. Acredito que seja suficiente para resolver seu problema.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

contas= pd.read_csv('contas.csv', sep = ';')

# Obtém todas as entradas que contém Doppler ou EcoDoppler na coluna "servico"
df_doppler = contas[(contas['servico'] == 'Doppler') |  contas['servico'] == 'EcoDoppler']

# Quantidade de exames com valores unitários("vl_unit") 30% acima ou abaixo do valor de referência("vl_ref").
# Obtém os valores do dataframe em formado de array (numpy)
values = contas.values
# Obtém o nome das colunas
column_names = contas.column


# Obtém os índices das colunas val_unit e val_ref
val_unit_idx = np.where(column_names == 'val_unit')
val_ref_idx = np.where(column_names == 'val_ref')
# Itera os dados presentes do dataframe para buscar valores que satisfaçam a condição
val_match = []
for entry in values:
  if( (entry[val_unit_idx] == entry[val_ref_idx] * 1.3) or  (entry[val_unit_idx] == entry[val_ref_idx] * 0.7) ):
    # Adiciona a linha do dataframe (em formato de array) na lista val_match
    val_match.append(entry)
```